# Is there a way to retrieve the current profile from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, command-line-interface, single-sign-on

I'm in the process of creating a CLI tool that does some configuration based on the output from AWS SSO. Essentially I'm trying to grab the profile that's associated with the current profile I'm logged into. If I can get the name of the profile I can look at the `~/.aws/config` values and retrieve the information I need to make an API call.

The application is written in Go, however, I'm totally fine with running an `exec` command against the system to find the profile settings for the currently logged in AWS session.

Is there a command that can be run that returns the current AWS Profile being used for CLI calls?

Comment: try `aws sts get-caller-identity`

Comment: Thank you @Red Cricket. That only returns the `UserId`, `Account` and `Arn` as long as I'm already supplying the `--profile` attribute. If I omit the `--profile` it says that I have an expired token. When using `aws sso login` I would assume there's somewhere the profile being used is saved, but I haven't been able to find it to this point.

Comment: Your profile is picked up from the ~/.aws/credentials. Would be worth checking the defined profiles on there. If there are multiple i think it will pick the default profile defined in credentials. Additionaly, if you have set the env variable AWS_PROFILE, it will use that profile and ignore other settings. Again all of this depends on other settings on your system as well.. There is an order of precendence that determines what credentials are used for the cli execution. It may not always be the profile

Comment: There is no concept of being "logged into" a profile. Each API call is independent and the profile can be specified when running the AWS CLI. If no profile is specified, it will use the default profile.

Comment: AWS SSO Login actually *does* have something like a concept of being "logged in".  The SSO Login flow handles the saml /oidc thing and ends ups with a token that's good for a configurable time, usually a number of hours.  That token is then used to get temporary credentials for any profile using sso under the aws config.  If `--profile` is required, it means your `default` profile is probably not set to use sso.

Answer (score 1):

An usual practice is set the profile with:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=your-profile
```

and then you can check your profile with:

```
echo $AWS_PROFILE
```